# MATLAB: Density-time Plot

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, density-plot

I have 11 1x50 matrices that contain densities. The first looks like [20, 20, 20... 20] and represents time=0. The second looks like [20, 19, 22,..], etc. and represents time=100. These continue to vary until t=1000.

What I'm hoping to do is to create a plot with the elements' position on the x-axis (50 positions for the 50 pieces of data in each) and time (0-1000) on the y-axis. Ideally, I'd like the plot to be completely filled in with color densities, and a colorbar on the side that shows what densities the color range represents.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Sort of inspired by: http://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2012/dont_use_scatterplots.html

Comment: Any ideas @rayryeng? You were very helpful yesterday!

Comment: Hello again.  Is this a 2D matrix that contains these 11 vectors, or are these 11 individually named vectors?  BTW, the answer to this is very easy.

Comment: That's good to hear! I have 11 individually named vectors.

Comment: Yuck :(.  OK, I'll leave it to you to construct these into a 2D matrix.  Assuming that, I'll write my answer.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Do you really have 11 separated 1x50 matrices? It's much better to arrange them into a 11x50 matrix

Comment: I had to read-in the data from separate files, so yeah, they were separate vectors before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have (or can arrange to have) all those vectors as columns of a 11x50 matrix:

```
A = randi(100, 11,50); %//example data
```

you can just use

```
imagesc(1:50, 0:100:1000, A)
colorbar
axis xy %// y axis increasing, not decreasing
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: +1 as well.  I was about to comment on inverting the axis, but it looks like you already did it in your edit!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the comments, it will be easier to stack these vectors into a 2D matrix.  You have 11 individually named vectors.  Assuming that your vectors are named `vec1`, `vec2`, `vec3`, etc., create a 2D matrix `A` that stacks these vectors on top of each other.  Also, you'll need to include an extra row and column at the end of this matrix that contains the **minimum over all of your vectors**.  The reason why this is will be apparent later, but for now take my word for it as this is what you need.

In other words:

```
A = [vec1; vec2; vec3; vec4; vec5; vec6; vec7; vec8; ...
     vec9; vec10; vec11];
minA = min(A(:));
A = [A minA*ones(11,1); minA*ones(1,51)];
```

As such, the first row contains the information at time 0, the next row contains information at time 100, etc. up to time 1000.

Now that we have that finished, we can use the [`pcolor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) function to plot this data for you.  `pcolor` stands for **pseudo-coloured checkerboard plot**.  You call this by doing:

```
pcolor(A);
```

This will take a matrix stored in `A` and produce a checkerboard plot of your data.  Each point in your matrix gets assigned a colour.  The colours get automatically mapped so that the least value gets mapped to the lowest colour while the highest value gets mapped to the highest colour.  `pcolor` does not plot the last row and last column of the matrix, but `pcolor` does **use all of the data** in the matrix.  In order to ensure that the colours get properly mapped, we need to pad your matrix so that the last row and last column get assigned to the smallest value over all of your vectors.  As you want to plot **all values** in the matrix, that's why we did what we did above.

Once we do this, we'll need to modify the X and Y ticks so that it conforms to your data.  As such:

```
pcolor(A);
set(gca, 'XTick', 0.5:5:51.5);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', 0:5:50);
set(gca, 'YTick', 1.5:11.5);
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', 0:100:1000);
xlabel('Sample Number');
ylabel('Time');
colorbar;
```

What the code does above is that it generates a checkerboard pattern like what we talked about.  This labels the Sample Number on the x axis while time is on the y axis.  You'll see with the two `set` commands that I did, this is a bit of a hack.  The y axis by default labeled the ticks going from 1 - 12.  What I did was that I changed these labels so that they go from 0 to 1000 in steps of 100 instead and I also removed the tick of 12.  In addition, I have made sure that these labels go **in the middle** of each row.  I do this by setting the `YTick` property so that I add 0.5 to each value going from 1 - 11.  Once I do this, I then change the labels so that they go from 0 - 1000 in steps of 100.  I also do the same for the x axis in a similar fashion to the y axis.  I then add a `colorbar` to the side as per your request.

Following the above code, and generating random integer data that is between 13 and 27 as per your comments:

```
A = randi([13,27], 11, 50);
minA = min(A(:));
A = [A minA*ones(11,1); minA*ones(1,51)];
```

We get:

[image]

Obviously, the limits of the colour bar will change depending on the dynamic range of your data.  I used `randi` and generated random integers within the range of 13 to 27.  When you use this code for your purposes, the range of the colour bar will change depending on the dynamic range of your data, but the colours will be adjusted accordingly.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 Definitely more complete and polished than my answer!

Comment: Thanks! That looks good. The only issue I have is that the data is only in the top half of the color range, so that the plot is all dark red - yellow. How can I change it so that it includes the green/blue spectrum?

Comment: @SjoFo679 Really?  It should automatically scale it so that the smallest and largest elements of your matrix maps to the lowest and highest colour.... that's pretty weird.  Either way, Luis Mendo's solution is more elegant.

Comment: Well the matrix has those zeroes included, so the colorbar is starting at zero but the data really starts around 15. I don't see how Luis' solution accounts for that.

Comment: @SjoFo679 That's why.  `pcolor` seems to be plotting the zeroes when it shouldn't.  If you created the matrix properly, you should see the matrix having its last column and last row of entirely zeroes. `pcolor` should disregard these.... but that code should work.  That's the code I used.  Either way, his code is much shorter.  Now I'm curious. Can you post this data so I can try and recreate it on my end?

Comment: The last column and last row are all zeroes... Here's the data:

Comment: 0 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20

Comment: Actually, I can't post it all at once. The numbers are seemingly random from 13 to 27, becoming less uniform as time increases.

Comment: @SjoFo679 - OK, you said they are in data files.  Can you post these somewhere?  It's up to you.  You don't have to.  I'm just curious as to why it's plotting zeroes when it shouldn't.  If not, 13 - 27? No values outside of this?

Comment: @SjoFo679 - Yup. I need to get rid of that zero padding.  One moment.

Comment: There is no data outside that range. When I take out the zero column and row, the colors span the whole range (but now all the data isn't included).

Comment: @SjoFo679 - Yup, the reason why is because `pcolor` uses **all** of the data, but only displays the data without the last row and column.  As such, we need to replace the zeroes with the **minimum** of all of the data.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: @SjoFo679 - Done.  Check it out.  Thanks for the spot!

Comment: @rayryeng Great! Everything is working! In case you want to edit, in your first spot of code "A = [A minA*ones(11,1); minA*ones(1,11)];" has a little error - it should be "A = [A minA*ones(11,1); minA*ones(1,51)];". Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @SjoFo679 - D'oh!  Nice spot.  Thanks :)  You're also very welcome.

Comment: @rayryeng: +1 nice explanation. We could also pad with NaN values without affecting the data range, as in: `A = randi([13 27], [11 50]); A(end+1,:)=nan; A(:,end+1)=nan; pcolor((1:51)-0.5, (0:100:1100)-50, A)`. Note that `pcolor` is really just a `surface` call with ZData=0 and CData=matrix. This should explain the weird behavior with the bilinear interpolation between each four points to define a color rectangle (this is why the last row/col are not shown). I usually avoid using `pcolor` in favor of `image`/`imagesc`/`imshow` for that reason :)

Comment: @Amro - That's good to know.  This is the second question I have answered where `imagesc` was favoured over `pcolor`.... so the universe is telling me that I should just use `imagesc` instead!  Also, awesome tip with `NaN`.  I always forget about how that doesn't affect the data being plotted.  Also very good to know with regards to the `surface` call.  I learn something new everyday from you!